# make UIPanGesture follow lines

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to move a red dot, following this board lines :

[image]

The red dot is an instance of Dot class that is a subclass of UIImage view :

```
class Dot: UIImageView {

enum directions {
    case up, down, left, right, nordWest, nordEst, southWest, southEst
}

var position: Int = 4

var possibleDirections: [directions] {
    switch position {
    case 0:
        return [.right, .down, .southEst]
    case 1:
        return [.left, .right, .down]
    case 2:
        return [.left, .down, .southWest]
    case 3:
        return [.up, .down, .right]
    case 4:
        return [.up, .down, .left, .right, .nordWest, .nordEst, .southWest, .southEst]
    case 5:
        return [.up, .down, .left]
    case 6:
        return [.up, .right, .nordEst]
    case 7:
        return [.up, .left, .right]
    case 8:
        return [.up, .left, .nordWest]
    default:
        return []
    }
}

}
```

Here's my viewController :

```
    @IBOutlet weak var redDot: Dot!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    redDot.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector( moveDot(_:) ))
    redDot.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}


@objc func moveDot(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began, .changed:
        moveDotWith(gesture: sender)
    case .ended, .cancelled:
        proceedToMove()
    default:
        break
    }
}

private func moveDotWith(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = gesture.translation(in: redDot)
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: translation.y)
    redDot.transform = transform

}

private func proceedToMove() {

}
```

I want to make in sort that the moveDotWith(gesture) function only allows to move the dot following lines, then the proceedToMove function will save the change with `redDot.position = (Int)`

I think I'm able to save the changes but I don't have any idea how to make the red dot follow lines and so only in allowed directions.

The positions goes from 0 to 8, like that :

[image]

I want the users can't drag the dot in blank areas, just along the lines, then if the user release the dot, it goes to the nearest point.

exemple: Red dot is at 1, if the user attempt to drag it to 3, nothing happens. if the user drag it to 2, the dot follows the gray line, then when user releases it, if the dot is more than half of the line, it goes to 2, else it come back to 1.

Comment: When the user lifts his finger after dragging the dot, do you want it to "snap" to the closest point?

Comment: Yeah It's exactly that I want, but only if there is a line between the departure and the destination points. I have 9 hidden entities that are at the corrects positions, to place the dot at the correct positions easily.

Comment: Add some "plain language" logic to your question, to make it clear. For example, if `redDot` is at `7` and the user drags and releases it near `5`, what should happen? Should it jump to `4`? or `8`? Or only jump if it is within, say, 10% of the distance to `4`? When you have written out your desired logic, you may have your answer already.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take a bit of math work, but one approach...

Change your "possibleDirections" to "possibleEndPoints":

```
var possibleEndPoints: [Int] {
    switch position {
    case 0:
        return [1, 3, 4]
    case 1:
        return [0, 2, 4]
    case 2:
        return [1, 4, 5]
    case 3:
        return [0, 4, 6]
    case 4:
        return [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    case 5:
        return [2, 4, 8]
    case 6:
        return [3, 4, 7]
    case 7:
        return [4, 6, 8]
    case 8:
        return [4, 5, 7]
    default:
        return []
    }
}
```

Now, when the user is dragging, you'll want to calculate the distance to a point on a line perpendicular to the drag-point:

[image]

So,

- `position` == 0
- `possibleEndPoints` == `[1, 3, 4]`
- `DP` is the drag-point
- `A` is the point on line `0 -> 1`
- `B` is the point on line `0 -> 4`
- `C` is the point on line `0 -> 3`

The shortest line will be the "closest point" to a valid line segment, so you would move `redDot` to that point - in this case, `A`. When the user lifts his finger, calculate "is `A` more than 50% of the way to `1`".

As the user continues dragging, you might reach:

[image]

Now `B` is the closest point to the drag-point, so move `redDot` to `B`. When the user lifts his finger, calculate "is `B` more than 50% of the way to `4`".

You'll have to account for cases when the users drags *past* a valid point, as in:

[image]

You'll have to come up with your own logic to decide where `redDot` should go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer, i'm not at home i'll try to implement this later !